# SQL returns data but the corresponding Linq statement returns no data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I have the following tables:

```
Operators
    OperatorId (int)
    Username (varchar)
    IsActive (bit)

EventLogs
    ...
    UserID (varchar)
    ...
```

The following SQL statement returns 2 rows of data as these are the only 2 Operators that have data within the EventLogs table:

```
select distinct o.OperatorId, o.Username, o.IsActive
from Operators o
join EventLogs e on CAST(o.OperatorId AS VARCHAR) = e.UserID
where e.UserID != 'NULL'
```

Using [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/), it produced the following Linq statement:

```
(from o in db.Operators
join e in db.EventLogs on SqlFunctions.StringConvert((Double)o.OperatorId) equals e.UserID
where
    e.UserID != "NULL"
select new {
    o.OperatorId,
    o.Username,
    o.IsActive
}).Distinct()
```

I'm having a hard time understanding and writing the correct Linq statement in order to return the same information.

I have tried to CAST the e.UserID as INT which returns the same 2 results in SQL and a different result in Linq using the [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/) tool:

SQL

```
select distinct o.OperatorId, o.Username, o.IsActive
from Operators o
join EventLogs e on o.OperatorId = CAST(e.UserID AS INT)
where e.UserID != 'NULL'
```

Linq

```
(from o in db.Operators
join e in db.EventLogs on new { OperatorId = o.OperatorId } equals new { OperatorId = (int?)(int)(Int32)e.UserID }
where
      e.UserID != "NULL"
select new {
      OperatorId = (int?)o.OperatorId,
      o.Username,
      o.IsActive
}).Distinct()
```

The difference being is that this Linq doesn't even compile.

Fails on the join with `The type arguments cannot be inferred from the query.` and the `(Int32)` cast fails with `Cannot cast expression of type 'string' to type 'int'`

I am fine with the original attempt using the `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` to convert the o.OperatorId as a string.

Comment: Are you actually storing rows with the value `NULL` as a string literal in the `UserID` column?

Comment: @martin-smith Yes. `NULL` is the default value when inserting an EventLog entry if there isn't a UserID (OperatorId) to insert. Not my choice. Just working with what I have.

Comment: Are you permitted to create a stored procedure? If so, you could use the working SQL and then call the stored procedure with LINQ. It would potentially simplify your code. I don't always recommend that, but you're in a case where LINQ makes it harder to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was fortunate enough to be able to run SQL Profiler since this is a dev server.

```
SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)o.OperatorId)
```

in C# equates to

```
STR( CAST( OperatorId AS float))
```

in SQL.

The resulting float value in SQL contains leading and trailing white space.

So

```
WHERE (N'1' = (STR( CAST( [Extent1].[OperatorId] AS float)))) OR (N'2' = (STR( CAST( [Extent1].[OperatorId] AS float))))
```

will not find a match unless the SQL contains an `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` wrapped around the `CAST`

By adding `SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)o.OperatorId).Trim()` in the C# Linq, it trims the white space in the resulting SQL and returns the expected values.